# Split issue in Turkish alphabet

Tags: python, parsing

I am getting some sentences from an XML file and I am trying to split these sentences into the words (using space as a separator). However, I have lots of Turkish words in the XML file. For example, when I print "Bugün", everything is okay it prints this word well but, when I split the sentence, it now prints "u'Bug\xfcn".

Here it is what I is my code seems like;

```
for tweet in root.findall('tweet'):
    text = tweet.find('text').text
    myList = re.split(" ", text)
    print(text) # This prints "Bugün"
    print(myList) # This prints "Bug\xfcn"
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? It looks like you have an encoding issue.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.10

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html